# JUCE unable to insert button on audio plugin

Tags: c++, juce

I'm attempting to add a button in an audio plugin, but can't seem to get it to display when testing.

I'm using the plugin host to test, and view the GUI. `pad1` is defined in `PluginEditor.h`:

```
private:
    // This reference is provided as a quick way for your editor to
    // access the processor object that created it.
    CPAudioProcessor& processor;

    TextButton pad1;
```

I've placed the following code in `PluginEditor.cpp`:

```
CPAudioProcessorEditor::CPAudioProcessorEditor (CPAudioProcessor& p)
    : AudioProcessorEditor (&p), processor (p)
{
    pad1.setColour(TextButton::buttonColourId, Colours::lime);
    pad1.setButtonText("Press Me!");
    addAndMakeVisible(pad1);

    // Make sure that before the constructor has finished, you've set the
    // editor's size to whatever you need it to be.
    setSize (400, 300);
}
```

I was following this tutorial as a guide on how to add the button: https://www.juce.com/doc/tutorial_rectangle_advanced

Is there anything I'm missing? It looks the same as the code in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I forgot to set the width/height in the overridden `resized` method.

```
void CPAudioProcessorEditor::resized()
{
    // This is generally where you'll want to lay out the positions of any
    // subcomponents in your editor..
    pad1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```